# converting json into this format

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON:

```
{
 "api":{
   "@api" : "{get}",
   "method" : "/user/:id",
   "message" : "Request User information"  
   },
   "@apiName" : "GetUser"
}
```

How can I convert it to the following (API documentation) format?

```
/**
 * @api {get} /user/:id Request User information
 * @apiName GetUser
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple. Just a matter of string concatenation and navigating the JSON object. Might be cleaner, if done with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```
function convertToDocumentationComment (json) {
    var str = '/**\n'
    str += ('* @api ' + json.api['@api'] + ' ' + json.api.method + ' ' + json.api.message + '\n')
    str += ('* @apiName ' + json.api['@apiName'] + '\n')
    str += '*/'
    return str
}
```

Here's a test:

```js
function convertToDocumentationComment (json) {
    var str = '/**\n'
    str += ('* @api ' + json.api['@api'] + ' ' + json.api.method + ' ' + json.api.message + '\n')
    str += ('* @apiName ' + json.api['@apiName'] + '\n')
    str += '*/'
    return str
}

var json = {
 "api":{
   "@api" : "{get}",
   "method" : "/user/:id",
   "message" : "Request User information"  
   },
   "@apiName" : "GetUser"
}
var r = convertToDocumentationComment(json)
document.write(r.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm correctly interpreting your question, but are you trying to generate documentation blocks of that using data from some JSON?

If so, you can use JSON.parse, then access the properties you need to build your string. I would probably use replaces in a template, like below (but that's far from the fastest method, I'm sure)

Your description of the format is missing, but you'll need to follow that to determine how to usethis.

```
var k = JSON.parse('{"@api" : "{get}"}');

var paramTpl = "* {name} {method} {message}\n";
var parameter = paramTpl.replace('{name}', k["@api"]);
```